# python celery - ImportError: No module named _curses - while attempting to run manage.py celeryev

Tags: python, celery, curses

**Background**

Windows 7 x 64
Python 2.7
Django 1.4
Celery with Redis bundle

While trying to run manage.py celeryev, I get the following error in the terminal

```
import curses
File 'c:\Python2\lib\curses\__init__.py', line 15, in <module> from _curses import *
ImportError: No module named _curses
```

I've tried looking at other posts, but haven't been able to solve this problem. Any thoughts on what is causing this error? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

According to http://docs.python.org/library/curses.html the curses module is only supported on Unix platforms. Try the Windows binaries from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#curses.

Comment: Thanks! First time programming python on windows!

Answer (score 0):

According to https://pypi.org/project/windows-curses/ the curses module can be installed on Windows platforms by:

```
pip install windows-curses
```