# Install .whl error

Tags: python, python-2.7, curses

I want to use `curses` module in windows.So I found

[python celery - ImportError: No module named _curses - while attempting to run manage.py celeryev](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10488826/python-celery-importerror-no-module-named-curses-while-attempting-to-run-m)

And when I want to install, I am getting an error.

I am running

```
pip install curses-2.2-cp34-none-win32.whl
pip install curses-2.2-cp34-none-win_amd64.whl
pip install --use-wheel curses-2.2-cp34-none-win32.whl
pip install --use-wheel curses-2.2-cp34-none-win_amd64.whl
```

All it does is display this error:

> curses-2.2-cp34-none-*.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.

Why? How can I solve it?

Comment: you probably want the cp27 wheel (cp34 is for CPython 3.4)

Comment: I'll add this as an answer I guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want the cp27 wheel (cp34 is for CPython 3.4)

Comment: I had recorded it in [blog](http://qianchenglong.github.io/2015/01/26/python-install-curses-on-windows).